# JQuery: Selecting a page's visible text

Tags: jquery, html

I understand that you can select a page's HTML with something like `$("body").html`, but I was wondering if it's possible to select the visible contents of the HTML?

For example, the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <p>Main copy text</p>
</div>
```

Instead of selecting all the HTML, you'd be able to just get:

```
Hello!Main copy text
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/MntuX/3/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/MntuX/2/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/MntuX/

Api: `.text()` link http://api.jquery.com/text/

**code**

```
$(function(){
    alert($('div').text());
});​
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('div').text());
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure is possible:

[jQuery Text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)